# How to specify Spring `ApplicationContext` object to a SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to get a `@SpringBootApplication` to load a jar at runtime with `@SpringBootTest`s and run them but `@SpringBootTest` tries to instantiate a new `ApplicationContext` and fails. Is there a way to tell the `@SpringBootTest` to instantiate a new `ApplicationContext` only if one doesn't already exist (so as not to hinder development, the test must be runnable from outside the context of the app) and to reuse the existing one if it does?

When the app is running and tries to run the test, it throws `InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication`.

Comment: where is your code and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom loader that will, by default, delegate to `SpringBootContextLoader` but allows overriding that default behavior:

```
public class SharedApplicationContextLoader extends SpringBootContextLoader {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SharedApplicationContextLoader.class);

  @SpringBootApplication
  public static class ApplicationContextSourceFallback {
  }

  private static final AtomicReference<Supplier<ApplicationContext>> applicationContextSupplier = new AtomicReference<>();

  private static final AtomicReference<ApplicationContext> applicationContext = new AtomicReference<>();

  @Override
  public ApplicationContext loadContext(final MergedContextConfiguration config) {
    applicationContextSupplier.compareAndSet(null, () -> {
      try {
        return super.loadContext(config);
      } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    });

    applicationContext.compareAndSet(null, applicationContextSupplier.get().get());

    return applicationContext.get();
  }

  public static void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    SharedApplicationContextLoader.applicationContextSupplier.set(() -> applicationContext);
  }
}
```

In the test, use that custom loader:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {
        MyAppCrucibleTestsConfiguration.class,
        SharedApplicationContextLoader.ApplicationContextSourceFallback.class},
    loader = SharedApplicationContextLoader.class)
class MyAppTest {
}
```

In the `SpringBootApplication`-annotated class, override that default:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyAppCrucibleTestsConfiguration.class})
public class MyAppCrucible {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SharedApplicationContextLoader.setApplicationContext(
      SpringApplication.run(MyAppCrucible.class, args));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add jar to your classpath. And use SpringBoot application from this jar in following way:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=com.example.demo.DemoApplication.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

DemoApplication.class is the @SpringBootApplication from the added jar.

But there will be compilation error, if DemoApplication.class is not in your classpath.